# Eloquent model inheritance - multi-table design

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, eloquent

Assume we have two db tables: `posts` and `threads`:

```
threads
   id - integer
   title - string
posts
   id - integer
   body - text
   created_at - timestamp
   thread_id - integer (fk)
```

and two Eloquent models:

```
class Post extends Model { 

   public function thread()
   {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Thread');
   }  
}


class Thread extends Post { 

   protected $table = 'threads';

   public function post()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
   } 
}
```

What I want to achieve is `Thread` object having `id, title, body, created_at` attributes, while `Post` object having `id, body, created_at` attributes.

Yet, I still get error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'body' in 'field list'

which is MySQL error that basically means that Laravel's trying to look up the `body` column in the `threads` table. However, it is stored in the `posts` table.

Comment: How you have defined Relationship?

Comment: That looks like a MySQL error - does the column really exist in the DB?  Also, show us the code which generates the error.

Comment: How do you access model's fields in code?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, it is MySQL error. It's looking for body field in the threads table, which obviously is not there...

Comment: @GauravRai just added the relationships

Comment: Thread::with('post') -> get();

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is unnecessary with Eloquent.

The data that is retreived from the database iss storred in the `$attributes` property.

So unless you are sharing any behaviour you don't need to inherit from anything other than `Model`.

Comment: I believe it is, because the `Thread` object as represented by the `threads` table is not meaningful without the `Post` object attributes.

Answer (score -1):

OK, so here is my updated answer after some research on your question. As you have defined table schema i.e

```
threads
   id - integer
   title - string
posts
   id - integer
   body - text
   created_at - timestamp
   thread_id - integer (fk)
```

This means `Thread` has many or just one (depends on relation) `Post`, and `Post` belongs to `Thread`, so the relationship would be something like this

```
class Thread extends Model{ 
   protected $table = 'threads';
   public function post()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Post');//Or hasOne('App\Post')
   } 
}
class Post extends Model { 
   public function thread()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Thread');
   }  
}
```

What you want to achieve is `Thread` object having `id, title, body, created_at` attributes, while `Post` object having `id, body, created_at` attributes.

Now according to current scene, One `Thread`, may have more than one `Post`. Here you'll always get `body` and `created_at` in relationship for object `Thread` e,g `Thread::with('post')->get();`, and vice versa

Comment: That's not really answering my question. That's just a workaround that would get complete data for `Thread`, while still being just a `Post` instance.